# ANTLR 4 map Java Exception to directly with DSL input script

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

In ANTLR 4 inside Listener, I can listen for rule events. In listener event suppose I am performing any task and that task is failed. At task failure I would like to notify DSL user about failure by referring DSL script(not specific to Java code). And stop further execution of tree traversing.

**How I should accomplish this ?**

> NOTE: One way is to get line number from context and notify about
>   failure referring to that line input. But I would like to know if
>   there is any mechanism provided by ANTLR?

Answer (score 0):

This type of task is best handled by an implementation of the `ANTLRErrorStrategy` interface. In particular, look at the runtime provided `BailErrorStrategy` class.